# Authentication User/Password API Call | PHP

Tags: php, api, authentication

I try to call an API that returns me a JSON file :

https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf/stop_areas/stop_area:OCE:SA:87391003/departures?datetime=20180323T085700

As you'll notce, there is an authentication box asking for a user and password.

I got a token (that is made of just a username, no password, check the script below) but I can't manage to get trouht that authentication.

I've tried this :

```
<?php
$host='https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf/stop_areas/stop_area:OCE:SA:87391003/departures?datetime=20180323T085700';
$json_source=file_get_contents($host);
$username="d96395d8-342d-4be4-8ed3-5909624abc57";
$password="";
$additionalHeaders="";
$payloadName="";
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $additionalHeaders));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_close($process);

$data = json_decode($json_source);
var_dump($data);
foreach ($data->departures as $a) {
    echo $a->display_informations->direction. '<br />';
}
?>
```

but it doesn't workd, I keep having this error :

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 3

and so if I do a `var_dump($data)` I got a `Null` variable.

On internet the example are mainly about specifying the certificate to overcome that SSL issue, but in my case that's a user/password that I need to provide and I haven't been able to get that to work using the example I found on internet so I come to you.

Comment: The error you are getting IS about the SSL. Its not even getting to the point where you need to worry about the user/pass auth. So, tackle one issue at a time :) Need to setup a cacert for curl to use. Once you get rid of the SSL failed error, then you can worry about the user/pass auth (which is far easier to deal with).

Comment: So am I supposed to install a cert on my server or should I download their cert in order to setup curl ?

Comment: Either one. Sometimes (from experience) the global cert doesnt contain what you need, and you end up having to grab the one from the host (or their provider). Like I've had bad luck with RapidSSL certs in the last year, needing to pull those directly to add to get some API's to work.